# pandas to_datetime from two text columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following time-series of the format below.

What's the easiest way to convert/combine columns 'date' and 'time' into a pandas datetime format?

I know it should be pandas.to_datetime(date...). But I can't figure out the format to combine them.

```
  ccy      date  time    open    high     low   close
0  EURUSD  20190211   100  1.1318  1.1319  1.1317  1.1319
1  EURUSD  20190211   200  1.1320  1.1322  1.1319  1.1319
2  EURUSD  20190211   300  1.1318  1.1319  1.1318  1.1319
3  EURUSD  20190211   400  1.1319  1.1319  1.1318  1.1318
4  EURUSD  20190211   500  1.1318  1.1318  1.1318  1.1318
```

Comment: Btw, how do we have to read your `time` column. Is `100` 1 am?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do the conversion, but you need to make sure the time column makes sense - your table is ambiguous right now when displaying 3 digits for time. Also, make sure your date and time columns are strings, else convert them to strings because joining them sensibly will require it.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['20190211','20190211'],'time':['0100','0200']})
pd.to_datetime(df['date']  + df['time'], format='%Y%d%m%H%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `date` and `time` are currently stored as integers. Therefore you might need to cast them as strings in order to perform string slicing.

```py
def convert_to_datetime(date, time):
    datestr = str(date)
    timestr = str(time)
    result = datestr[0:4] + "/" + datestr[4:6] + "/" + datestr[6:]
    result = result + " " + timestr[0:-2] + ":"+ timestr[-2:]
    return pd.to_datetime(result)

df["datetime"] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_to_datetime(x["date"], x["time"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

#### First method: (without pandas)

```
# convert date
data['ddate']= [str(dt)[:4]+'-'+str(dt)[4:6]+'-'+str(dt)[-2:] for dt in 
# convert time 
data['dtime']= [str(dt)[:-2]+':'+str(dt)[-2:] for dt in data['dtime']]
# join 
data['datetime'] = data['ddate'] + ' ' + data['dtime'] # space or whatever you want
# delete unneeded columns 
del data['ddate'], data['dtime']
```

#### Second method: (using pandas)

```
data['datetime']= pd.to_datetime([str(dt)+str(tm) for dt,tm in data[['date','time']].values],format='%Y%d%m%H%M')
```